# how to use pagecontrol for showing images within imageview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have an image view inside a scrollview and i am using a pagecontrol for scrolling images.The problem is only last image showing not the first two images.But when i scroll i can see the second image for some extend and then disappears.how to solve this issue.

Comment: `[yourScrollView setcontentSize:CGSize(width, height)];` Have you set this property properly. Here `width` should be `totalImages * widthOfImage` and `height` should be `yourScrollView Height`.

Comment: yea i have set that..but still same issue.

Comment: priyanka first google this, there are a lot of sample codes and examples explaning this.

Answer (score 2):

```
    memberScrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:memberScrollviewFrame];
    memberScrollview.pagingEnabled=YES;
    memberScrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.95 blue:0.95 alpha:0.2];
    memberScrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
    memberScrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    memberScrollview.delegate =self;
    memberScrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
    int scrollength = 50;
    memberScrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollength,60);
    memberImageArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    memberScrollViewImageArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:kmemberScrollViewImageArray];
    leftValue =0;


    for (int j=0; j<12; j++){


        if (j%3 == 0) {
            y = float2;
        }

        else if (j % 3 == 1) {
            //x = 32;
            y = float32;
        }        
        else if(j % 3 == 2) {
            //x = 62;
            y = float62;
           // leftValue += 30;
        }        
        profileImageViewFrame=CGRectMake(x,y,float28,float28);
        profileImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:profileImageViewFrame];            

        profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[memberScrollViewImageArray objectAtIndex:j]];
        [memberImageArray insertObject:profileImageView atIndex:j];

        profileImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        memberScrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x+float30,float90);

        [memberScrollview addSubview:[memberImageArray objectAtIndex:j]];

        if(j % 3 == 2) {
            x = x+float30;
        }
    }

    [thirdView addSubview:memberScrollview];
```

Comment: @priya check your content size